# watchOS 2 Reachability in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, watchos-2

I have looked around at some of the similar answers but none of these seem to be helping me.

I seem to be having a problem with my application. I have created the single view application and also added in the WCSessionDelegate into my extension.

```
import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate { }
```

I have also checked the session if the session is not there and told it to print out if it cant find it

```
guard WCSession.isSupported() else {
  print("Session is not supported")
  return
}

let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
session.delegate = self
session.activateSession()
```

However I am still getting a No WatchConnectivity error. I'm confused as If the session is working then I think I have it coded right?

Comment: Can you post full code and full error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

Whilst waiting for your code, I think I can see the issue. Where you have declared the session delegate as a delegate here:

```
import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate { }
```

You need to also import WatchConnectivity

like so:

```
import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate { }
```

Let me know if his helps!

## Tutorial

There is a tutorial which explains exactly this issue: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/watchos-2-checking-reachability/

## Plugin

Also in the same search is a nift plugin you can use: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift - This would be my option if you're not confident enough

## Tip

(Google is your friend)

Comment: Then I suggest you following the tutorial properly :-p I'm assuming that worked then? mind accepting the answer?